# Qt Creator precompiled headers code completion

Tags: qt-creator, code-completion, precompiled-headers

I have a problem with code completion in Qt Creator. I have a precompiled header named `OgreHeaders.h`. I am building with clang using qmake mkspec `unsupported/linux-clang`.
My project builds but when i edit it I don't get any code hints. I think this is because my precompiled header is included using `-include-pch` compiler option, not `#include` directive. So Qt Creator code model doesn't even find it. I had an idea about wrapping the header in `#ifdefs` or `#ifndefs` so it would parse it but not compile.

```
#ifdef PCH
#include <OgreHeaders.h>
#endif
```

I need to somehow `#define PCH` in Qt Creator code model, but not in the compiler's one. Or do the reverse. I tried using `QMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` and `DEFINES`, but Qt Creator picks them up.

I saw [this](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2011/10/19/qt-creator-and-clang/) article about integraton. At the bottom of the article is says:

> When you go to the “Projects” mode, you will see an extra tab with
>   “Code Completion Settings”, where you can select a “custom” header.
>   When selecting this option, the code-model will use that header as a
>   cache, but the compiler will not use it.

I don't have that option in my Qt Creator(2.8.0). Any ideas how to workaround this issue or I need to build Qt Creator with clang integration from git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put either

```
#define PCH
```

or

```
#undef PCH
```

to `PROJECT_NAME.config` file in your project's root directory, where `PROJECT_NAME` is name of your project in Qt Creator -- just like `PROJECT_NAME.files` and `PROJECT_NAME.includes`.

Comment: This changes Qt Creator code completion `#defines` or compiler's?

Comment: Yes, this file is only used by Qt Creator code completion and highlighting; it's not passed to preprocessor/compiler.